# Why are new tables being created instead of the same one being refreshed in my HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xpath

What do I have to do so that when *display* is clicked the table is refreshed? For now, whenever *display* is clicked a new table is created underneath the previous one.

When the page loads for the first time I want the whole of the table to be displayed (ie  the whole of my XML file(which is linked to an XSL file)  underneath the Input fields. How do I do that?

in IE (and not in Firefox) whenever the user clicks on the *display* button the input section is gone and only the table with the XML content is displayed. How do I get IE to keep the input fields and display the table underneath?
Here is a fragment of my code with all the essential parts hopefully... Thank you in advance!

```
<html>
.........
......
<script type="text/javascript">

function filterTable(f)
{
  ................
  .......
  if (moz)
  {
    ...........
    ....
    var proc = new XSLTProcessor();
    proc.importStylesheet(stylesheet);
    var resultFragment = proc.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, document);
    document.getElementById("target4").appendChild(resultFragment);
  }

  else if (ie)
  {
    .....
    ......
    value.setAttribute("select", "books/scifi" + filter);
    value2.setAttribute("select", sorter);

   document.write(xmlDoc.transformNode(stylesheet));
  }
}

</script>
<form>
  ...........
  ....
  <input type="button" value="Display" onClick="filterTable(this.form)"/>
</form>

<body id="target4">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your function is explicitly handling IE in a different way, using `document.write()` instead of `.appendChild()`, so it's not really a surprise that you get different behaviour. Also, your form element should be inside your body element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write() will overwrite the whole document, when used after the the document has been loaded. Use another method too to inject the new content, e.g. setting the innerHTML of an element(DOM-methods will not work here, because IE doesn't allow to move nodes between documents).

---

Related to the comments:

The markup for the table you get from

```
xmlDoc.transformNode(stylesheet)
```

You must 1st create an node from this markup:

```
  //create a dummy-wrapper
var wrapper=document.createElement('div');

  //insert the markup
wrapper.innerHTML=xmlDoc.transformNode(stylesheet);

  //inject the first child into the document
document.getElementById("target4").appendChild(wrapper.firstChild);

  //delete the wrapper, we don't need it anymore
delete wrapper;
```

Comment: I can't figure out how innerHTML works. Am I to include the result of my filterTable function in a innerHTML element? And how exactly do I do that because all the example I found online have to do with refreshing text on screen `document.getElementById('{ID of element}').innerHTML = '{content}'; ` in my case `content` is the result of my function filterTable.. right?

Comment: @user1073400 going with what you've said here, what you would want to do is something like add a div with an id foo, then do `document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = htmlOutputSerializedAsString;`

Comment: @cm2 `htmlOutputSerializedAsString` how do I do that?? How do I turn my function's output which a whole table into a `serialized string`?

Comment: htmlOutputSerializedAsString is a synonym for the result of transformNode(the markup for the table in this case), I've added an example to my answer

Comment: @Dr.Molle thank you for for adding the piece of code, unfortunately I still don't know where and how to use that..Do I put that block of code you've written at the end of my jScript function?

Comment: replace  the `document.write(xmlDoc.transformNode(stylesheet));` with the 2nd code-snippet (the 4 instructions from createElement to delete)

Comment: @Dr.Molle Thanks! This solves the problem of not losing the input fields in IE every time the table is displayed. However, I still get the same problem both in Moz & IE where the table is not refreshed for every new query, instead a new table is created underneath the previous one on the same page. How do I solve that?

Comment: When you want  to replace a node with another node, use replaceChild instead of appendChild https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.replaceChild

Comment: @Dr.Molle I'm now trying something like: `var old=document.getElementById("target4"); document.getElementById("target4").replaceChild(resultFragment, old);` but I get an error. Could it be that there s nothing to be replaced the first time the function is executed since the body of target4 is empty the first time?

Comment: #target 4 isn't a child of #target4, so this will not work. Instead of using replaceChild you still may use appendChild, but before set the innerHTML of #target4 to a empty string(this will remove the current content)